# How can I find the elapsed time from a specific date to now when using Pandas Timestamp in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe

| company_name | founded_on |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2004-01-01 00:00:00 |
| b | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
| c | 2008-01-01 00:00:00 |
| d | 1997-01-01 00:00:00 |

```
today = pd.Timestamp.now()
df["founded_on"]=pd.to_datetime(df["founded_on"])
df["Time_Since_founded_on"] = (today - df["founded_on"]).dt.days // 30
```

OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

I want to know how many months each companies have been in operation.

Answer (score 1):

Use monthly period operations, converting using [`to_period('M')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['Time_Since_founded_on'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['founded_on']).dt.to_period('M')
                                 .rsub(pd.Timestamp('today').to_period('M'))
                                 .apply(lambda x: x.n)
                              )
```

Output:

```
  company_name           founded_on  Time_Since_founded_on
0            a  2004-01-01 00:00:00                    242
1            b  2013-01-01 00:00:00                    134
2            c  2008-01-01 00:00:00                    194
3            d  1997-01-01 00:00:00                    326
```

Note that your original approach (using days) would give incorrect values for large periods since months are not exactly equal to 30D:

```
df['Time_Since_founded_on'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['founded_on'])
                                 .rsub(pd.Timestamp('today'))
                                 .dt.days.div(30)
                              )

  company_name           founded_on  Time_Since_founded_on
0            a  2004-01-01 00:00:00             246.066667  # +4M
1            b  2013-01-01 00:00:00             136.466667  # +2M
2            c  2008-01-01 00:00:00             197.366667  # +3M
3            d  1997-01-01 00:00:00             331.266667  # +5M
```

*A better (but not perfect) approximation would be to divide by `365.25/12`.*

###### handling invalid/missing dates

If dates are invalid/missing, you need to adapt the code to use `errors='coerce'` and `dropna` before extracting the number of months:

```
df['Time_Since_founded_on'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['founded_on'], errors='coerce')
                                 .dt.to_period('M')
                                 .rsub(pd.Timestamp('today').to_period('M'))
                                 .dropna().apply(lambda x: x.n)
                              )
```

Output:

```
  company_name           founded_on  Time_Since_founded_on
0            a  2004-01-01 00:00:00                  242.0
1            b  2013-01-01 00:00:00                  134.0
2            c  2008-01-01 00:00:00                  194.0
3            d  1997-01-01 00:00:00                  326.0
4            e                  NaT                    NaN
```

Comment: This is the error code when I try it :   "ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array"

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example that triggers this error? Does `pd.to_datetime(df['founded_on'])` alone trigger the error? What about `pd.to_datetime(df['founded_on'], errors='coerce')`?

Comment: Now the error has been changed : " 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'n' "

Comment: See update for a version that handles invalid/missing dates